# Woocommerce API REST not working since two weeks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a PHP file that uses the Woocommerce REST API to obtain a series of products. The PHP file worked perfectly until about two weeks ago. I use that same PHP file on several servers, and it has stopped working on all of them at the same time.

As much as I have tried with the api I can't get it to work, however I have tried it on a different website, and it has worked correctly, with the same code.

I do not understand why it has suddenly stopped working on several websites at the same time.

This is the code I use to call the woocommerce API.

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$url_API_woo = 'https://midominion.com';
$ck_API_woo = 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$cs_API_woo = 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$woocommerce = new Client( $url_API_woo, $ck_API_woo, $cs_API_woo, ['version' => 'wc/v3']);
```

Testing the authentication with POSTMAN works fine. So the credentials are fine.
However, as soon as it reaches the next loop, the PHP process stops and returns a 500 code.

```
$page = 1;

while (count($woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page))) > 0) {

    $woo_all_products = array_merge($woo_all_products, $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page)));
    $page++;
}
```

Automatic updates are disabled, so it shouldn't be a versioning problem.

The version of WordPress that I use is version 5.8.1.

The Woocommerce version I use is version 5.6.0

Any ideas on what may be failing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. check the php versions, 2. check the error log, 3. try to increase the allocated memory, it could be memory exhausted

Comment: The PHP version is 7.4, the same on all servers, including the one that works. 
Regarding the logs, they do not contribute much :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not given much info + code so it is hard to find the bug. my best guess, the culprit is the `count` function as your PHP version is 7 `count` accepts only countable objects or array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php *[and as a side note the code is not performance optimized]*

to debug the bug follow the below steps -

1. change the code with below snippet

> ```
> $page = 1;
> $products = $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));
> while ( is_array($products) && count($products) > 0) {
>   $page++;
>   $woo_all_products = array_merge($woo_all_products, $products);
>   $products = $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));
> }
> ```

if it resolves the issue then problem is with `count` function and the api is responding something that is not countable.

If it still fail change the condition with below and try again -

`is_countable($products) && count($products) > 0` Note: `is_countable` will not work with lower PHP version.

2. To find what causing the issue change the code with below snippet -

> ```
> $products = $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => 999));
>
> var_dump($products);
>
> die();
> ```

Here make the page number as big so it does not exists and query failed.
Then vardump it and check if it is null or anything that causes the `count` function to fail. Hopefully you will find the bug.

**Advice:**

*best practice :* always put the api call in try-catch block. i.e.-

```
$page = 1;

try {

    $products = $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));

    while ( is_array($products) && count($products) > 0) {

        $page++;
        
        $woo_all_products = array_merge($woo_all_products, $products);
        
        $products = $woocommerce->get('products', array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));
    }

} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something terrible happened: '. $e->getMessage();
}
```